# val(); returning nothing

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery... I'm trying to get the `val();` of a textarea... and it's not working. When I click on submit (that works!) the alert shows as `You said:` :(

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {

$(".comment_button").click(function() {

var test = $("#content").val();
var dataString = 'content='+ test;
alert('You said: ' + test);

});
});
</script>
<style>
#error, #success { display:none;}
</style>
<?php include 'inc/main.php'; ?>

<h1>Testing</h1>
<div id="error">Error...</div>
<div id="success">Success...</div>
<form name="form" action="ask.php" method="post">

<textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="content" id="content" name="thequestion"></textarea><br /><br />

<input name="submit" value="Submit!" type="submit" class="comment_button" />

</form>
<div id="flash"></div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Works for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/V7FpE/

Comment: just in case try to give the same name and id to the textarea

Comment: I bet you have a problem with your DOM, you might need to post the full html source because that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a little and it worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/EPMy2/2/.

The most major changes that I made were using the `.submit()` trigger, not `.click()`, as `.click()` doesn't allow you to (easily, if at all) prevent the form from submitting.

Here's the modified chunks:

```
$("#comment_form").submit(function() {
    var test = $("#content").val();
    var dataString = 'content=' + test;
    alert('You said: ' + test);

    return false; //To prevent submit.
});
```

And this:

```
<form name="form" id="comment_form" action="ask.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

try `$("#content").text()` instead :-)

Comment: I will accept this but I also found out I can use `var test = $('textarea#myquestion').val();`

Comment: @Jahkr, thanks, that bc in that selector you are specifying it as a `textarea`, earlier you were not ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Textarea tags don't have "value" attributes, only input tags do.  Use .text() or .html() instead.

Comment: [Yes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7).  Just because it works doesn't mean it's right.  :P